# Property undefined TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typeerror

I am getting a `TypeError` when executing the following code:

server.class.ts

```
import {Handlers} from './handlers.class';
export class Server{
    private _hInstance: Handlers;
    static _instance: Server;
    private constructor(){
        this._hInstance = new Handlers();
        this._hInstance.mymethod();
    }
    static instance(): Server{
        if(!!!Server._instance){
            Server._instance = new Server();
        }
        return Server._instance;
     }
}
```

handler.class.ts

```
import { Polo } from './../extapi/polo.class';
export class Handlers{
    private _polo: Polo;
    constructor(){
        this._polo = Polo.instance(); // same as Server.instance()
    }
    mymethod(){
        this._polo.someMethod(); // Error
}
```

The polo class uses the same technique of defining a single instance and, providing a static method `instance()` for returning the instance. That code, tested separately, works fine. The type error raises that property `_polo` of `undefined` cannot be read. This is really confusing as, the class `Polo` has been instantiated before invoking `someMethod` on its instance.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle for the problem? Where is the mymethod called?

Comment: @Harald `mymethod` has been invoked only in the constructor for the `Server` class. For clarification, the code base is lengthy and, I wasn't sure of posting the entire code (6 classes, 2 interfaces) so, I just took out the segment that was posing the problem. If the problem is not clear, then I would post the entire code (I would be glad to answer any other question). Thanks

Comment: @Harald jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mr0cool/bf9e8wmy/

Answer (score 0):

The property undefined error in the handlers class was due to the fact that, the Polo.instance() method was returning a reference to the statically initialized Polo object. Making it private in the handlers class means, that for every instance of Handler, there will be a new private property declared that will refer to the same static instance. When compiled, this does not throw any errors. When run, every time this._polo is accessed, it fails to refer to the statically defined instance and, results into referring to undefined. The solution is to change the this._polo from private to static.